# One page layout with timeline-story-board-like website

Tags: library, javascript, css

I wonder which Javascript library or CSS can mimic this website’s style:

http://0media.tw/yslin/

Comment: I haven't looked into that website but the likelyhood of being straight library like bootstrap is limited - even in cases where developers make heavy use of something like that there is almost always some customization. So basically you'll need to write your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at the website's source to see what libraries they use as well as CSS stylesheets:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/d3js/3.3.11/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/angular/1.2.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- custom files-->
<link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="img/favicon.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="s/css/main.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/skrollr/skrollr.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="s/js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="s/js/navbar.js"></script>
```